# Access vba runs slow

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following sub takes about 2 seconds to get to DisplayMessage("TEST"), then I have to wait 20 seconds before control return to the form that runs it.

```
Sub OpenWordDocPrivacy()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim MyDoc As String

On Error Resume Next 'Otherwise the next line causes error "ActiveX component can't creat object."
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Word isn't already running
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

MyDoc = conAddrPth & "Documents\GPSystems\Privacy.docm"

wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(MyDoc)

Set wdApp = Nothing
'Set wdDoc = Nothing
DisplayMessage ("TEST")

End Sub

Public Sub DisplayMessage(strmessage As String) 
    MsgBox strmessage, vbExclamation, conAppName 
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared all the code in your routine "DisplayMessage"

Comment: Also, is that the time when Word is NOT already running and must start up, or the time when Word is already running?

Comment: Public Sub DisplayMessage(strmessage As String)

    MsgBox strmessage, vbExclamation, conAppName

    End Sub

Comment: Word runs fine. Don't think I explained properly. When the code actually runs, we get an egg timer and we can't do anything to the form that runs the code. The problem is that the code seems to run as it should, the document opens afetr about 2 seconds, but the egg timer runs for another 20 seconds, when we have to wait to be able to use the form. Also, I didn't understand what/why you made th change to my code - didn't seem to be an actual change.

Comment: Further clarification: if we put DisplayMessage("TEST") above Set wdApp = Nothing, we get the message displayed after 2 seconds, but we still have to wait 20 seconds before we get control of the form again. If we put it at the end of the code, we have to wait 20 seconds to see the message.

Comment: Pretty much anything can happen when opening/closing a word document with macros, depending on the content of the document and the plugins you use. This is hardly reproducible, if you use a clean office install and a word document without macros it'll probably run fine.

Comment: The only change I made to your code, 1st time, was to include the "End Sub" into the code window- not the comments area; the 2nd time was to include your "DisplayMessage" sub in the code window. I never want to assume that any missing code is just peachy fine. I have a couple of suggestions in the next comment.

Comment: How about running several tests: (1) Manually open the 'Privacy.docm' document and see how long it takes; (2) Manually open a small document with no macros and check the timing.  Do any Word macros/code get executed with your document (i.e. AutoOpen, AutoExec, etc.)?

Comment: "Also, is that the time when Word is NOT already running and must start up, or the time when Word is already running?" The 20 seconds delay is when word has stopped running. It happens even if I un-comment Set wdDoc = Nothing.

Comment: It works fine with a word document without macros.

Comment: Then I believe your issue lies within the macro in Word. If I run your code, and open a document with NO macro, it takes a total of 4.77 seconds (if first time and Word is not open); or .66 seconds if 2nd time and Word is already open. However, the size of the Word document can add to the time also...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I inspected/tested the .docm file. It's there that the problem lies. The function of the file is to produce a pdf. So the solution is to produce the pdf via an Access Report. Here is the code in the .docm: Can't imagine that I'll ever get it to run quickly.

```
enter code here
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:="E:\Peter\Documents\GPSystems\DataSource.txt", LinkToSource:=True, Revert:=True, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther

With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="E:\Peter\Documents\GPSystems\Privacy Declaration.rtf", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="E:\Peter\Documents\GPSystems\Privacy Declaration.pdf", FileFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
ActiveDocument.Close (wdSaveChanges)
Word.Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```